# Check if a string representing float/unsigned int is too big

Tags: c, strtoull

I have a file containing strings representing `float` and `uint64_t` values.

I know exactly which string contains `float` values and which contains `uint64_t` values - that is not the problem I'm facing.

Here is how I convert them to their respective data-type:

```
char* t, v; 
uint64_t cn; 


cn = strtoull(t, &v, 10);

char* tt, vv; 
float cn2; 

cn2 = strtof(tt, vv);
```

But the problem arises at the following edge-case I want to catch:

Let's say the string for the `uint64_t` is `"99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"`

This can't be represented within 8 bytes and therefore causes an overflow resulting in `cn = 18446744073709551615`.

Same problem with the `float cn2`.

How can catch this behavior?

Comment: Why do you limit yourself to `float` instead of the more common `double`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because this would cost to much memory.

Comment: But using the similarly sized `uint64_t` is fine? Both it and `double` are eight bytes. What are your requirements? Are you targeting a small embedded system? Why then use `uint64_t` instead of the smaller `uint32_t`? Again, what are your requirements? What is the actual (underlying) problem you're trying to solve? On any modern PC-like system (including mobile phones and even some "embedded" devices and IoT hardware) such memory optimizations might be premature.

Comment: @stht55 For your question, `errno` is definitely the way to go, as explained in Eric Postpischil's comment and Some programmer dude's answer.  Just be aware that this is an unusual situation: The `strto*` functions are just about the only functions in the C library that work in this way.  For these functions, setting `errno` to 0 beforehand and checking it afterwards is the way to go.  But for most other functions, setting `errno` to 0 beforehand is meaningless — for most other functions, `errno` is only meaningful after the call *if the call has explicitly returned an error code*, like -1.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have to do work with matrices in coo format. The values are in single precision.

Comment: stht55, What should happen with input like 1) "-123", 2) "123abc", 3) "abc", 4) " "?

Comment: @Reinstatemonica before I check if the strings have the correct format beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtoull` provides an indication that the value is out of range. Consider this code:

```
#include <errno.h>
…
errno = 0; // Set error code to zero before call.
unsigned long long x = strtoull(t, &v, 10);
if (errno == ERANGE)
{
    // Handle out-of-range error.
}
```

This will reach the error case if the numeral in `t` is too large.

Note that if `t` contains a minus sign (but is not too large in magnitude), `strtoull` will return a value that is “negated” in the `unsigned long long` type (that is, a value wrapped around `ULLONG_MAX`+1) even though a negative value is out of range of the type; no error indication will be provided. So, if you want to detect all out-of-range cases, you must check `t` for a minus sign (possibly after leading white space) with a non-zero return value.

`strtof` provides sufficient information to distinguish cases, per C 2018 7.22.1.3 10:

- If the value is positive and too large, `HUGE_VALF` is returned and `errno` is set to `ERANGE`.
- If the value is negative and too large, `-HUGE_VALF` is returned and `errno` is set to `ERANGE`.
- If the value underflows the normal range, a small value is returned and `errno` is set to `ERANGE`.

Comment: When `unsigned long long` is wider than 64 bits, another test warranted `if (errno == ERANGE || x > UINT64_MAX)`

Comment: "But it will also reach the error case if the numeral in t is negative." Actually it won't, I just learnt. The standard says "If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type)". See this example: https://godbolt.org/z/sEo9qWc6x. Compare the first two tests - errno only gets set in the 3rd test (underflow/overflow).

Comment: I just checked if it works with `HUGE_VAL`. The string `"1.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112"` is cast to `"1.111111"` without setting `errno == ERANGE`

Comment: @stht55: 1.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112 is not outside the finite range of `float`. It is between 1 and 2, both of which are representable in the format. It is not exactly representable in the format, and this is considered normal for floating-point operations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes but in my case, no loss of precision is allowed so this should be caught.

Comment: @stht55 Checking for _exactness_ (no loss of precision) is extremely problematic.   Consider [`FLT_MIN`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485), as decimal text ,may be dozens of (e.g. 89)  characters long.  It is not specified that `strtof()` and friends use beyond a much smaller number of significant digits in the conversion.  To achieve your _exactness_ goal likely obliges your own crafted conversion code - an error-prone proposition.

Comment: @stht55 If you really can't tolerate loss of precision, you might want to ask a separate question about that.  In general, if you're converting a floating-point string in decimal to an actual floating-point value in binary, you virtually *always* have some loss of, or at least slight change in, precision.

Comment: For example, when converting decimal strings to conventional IEEE754 `float`, the input `"1.0"` is exact, and the input `"1.00000011920928955078125"` is exact, but the seemingly simpler value `"1.0000001"` between them is not exact, and arguably suffers "precision loss".

Answer (score 1):

According to [this `strtoull` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul), when an overflow happens it will return `ULLONG_MAX` *and* `errno` is set to `ERANGE`.

So you should set `errno` to zero before the call, and after could check for `ULLONG_MAX` and `errno == ERANGE` to see if overflow happens.

Similarly with [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) it will return [`HUGE_VALF`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/HUGE_VAL).

Comment: Testing `HUGE_VALF` is inadequate as `HUGE_VALF` may be returned for a normal case where the value is not out of range, in C implementations where infinity is not represented in the floating-point format. Additionally, `errno` should be set to zero before the call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but what if the value ist equal to `ULLONG_MAX`?

Comment: @stht55 If the actual input in the string is the same as `ULLONG_MAX`, then `errno` should still be zero after the call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just checked if it works with `HUGE_VAL`. The string "1.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112" is cast to "1.111111" without setting `errno == ERANGE`

Comment: @stht55 That's not an *overflow*, it's just loss of precision. BTW, I'm pretty sure that 1.111111 can't be exactly represented by a `float`.

Comment: @stht55 That's no an out of range problem. Is your problem with the floating point numbers that the input string have much higher precision than `float` can handle? That's a completely different problem. Perhaps you might want to check the number of digits in the integer and decimals parts to see if they individually are more than can be handled by a single-precision floating point number?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes might be an option. Just thought that this loss of precision also means that in the process the `of` flag will be set.

Answer (score 1):

**If values less than 0 need detection**

`strtoull("-1", ..., ...)` "wraps" and returns `ULLONG_MAX`.

`strto(u)ll()` converts to *at least* a 64-bit integer.  Plan for future growth where `unsigned long long` may exceed 64-bit.

Example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

uint64_t convert_str_uint64(const char *s, char **endptr, int base) {
  errno = 0;
  long long ival = strtoll(s, endptr, base);
  // Look for negative numbers
  if (ival < 0) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    return 0;
  }
  // We are done for many positive numbers
  if (*endptr > s && ival <= INT64_MAX && errno == 0) {
    return (uint64_t) ival;
  }

  // Input may still be a valid value more than INT64_MAX.
  errno = 0;
  unsigned long long uval = strtoull(s, endptr, base);

#if ULLONG_MAX > UINT64_MAX
  if (uval > UINT64_MAX) {
    uval = UINT64_MAX;
    errno = ERANGE;
  }
#endif

  return (uint64_t) uval;
}
```